# Need help with the meaning of つなぎには in this sentence [Cooking/ Cuisine]

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

There is a sentence about cooking here. Looks like this dish is hamburger steak (?) and this character is cooking in his house to treat someone (A-san)

> 挽肉ではなく固まりの肉を包丁で微塵になるまで叩き切り、焦げないように飴色になるまで炒めた玉ねぎと混ぜ合わせてある。
>
> 味付けは塩と胡椒と、たっぷりのナツメグ。**つなぎにはパン粉ではなく、砕いた麩を使うのがうまみたっぷりの肉汁を外に逃がさない秘訣だ**。
>
> ジュウジュウと食欲を誘う音色といい香りが漂う中、焼き上がったハンバーグをA-sanが並べてくれた皿へと鼻歌交じりに盛りつける。​

Answer (score 2):

> To thicken it (make it stick together), instead of panko, use crushed *fu* (which I guess is like bread crumbs); that's the secret of keeping meat liquid with lots of good flavor. (alternatively: locking in richly flavored liquid that oozes from the meat)

[つなぎ](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%B9%8B%E3%81%8E)

> Noun
> 3. thickener (e.g. in cooking); thickening; liaison

Comment: I also got an answer from a native JP ,he explained that in this case the meaning of this term is "the binding element"
Sometimes when making a hamburger steak you mix in the breadcrumbs, and sometimes eggs, as a binder to keep the meat from not falling apart when cooking, it's a common method of cooking. つなぎ here is a cooking term. うまみ basically means deliciousness, delicious flavor. The sentences are explaining the recipe.

Comment: @4chanuser You may get the structure wrong - it parses 「つなぎには...つかうの」（A)が「うまみ...逃さない」（B）秘訣だ = A is 秘訣 for B.

Comment: @4chanuser That's exactly right there in the rendering I gave you. I explained exactly like that.